# Get a projection of a grayscale image in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram, projection, gaussian

Supposse there is this image

[image]

How is it possible to get a histogram of this image across a specific pixel number either in x- or y-axis?

What I mean is given a pixel number in one axis, to get the "projection" on the other axis?

For this image I would expect a gaussian shape. Is this possible in matlab or is it better to use another software?

Comment: It's as easy as pie: Just [`plot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) a row `Image(i,:)` or a column `Image(:,j)`. (This is not really a *projection* though.) (Of course you have to convert the image to a black-white image first.)

Comment: That's also very easy using [imageJ](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/) and its `line tracing` option

Comment: @knedlsepp Thank you very much for your comment! I have no idea how to  plot it. I supposse Ihave to load it first which might be easy, but how to plot a column of an image? I am confused...

Comment: You might want to read/watch a short tutorial on MATLAB. This is not really hard and I don't want to take the joy of finding it out yourself! :-) Hint: It doesn't involve a lot more than I mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: @knedlsepp I was able to load the image using `A=imread(test.png)`. Then I could plot it using `image(A)`. To plot a slice I used `plot(A(:,200))` and it seems that it's working. Would you mind posting as an answer?

Comment: @Thanos: :-) Perfect! You can also post the answer to your own question. One more thing: The image you are reading might be a color image, i.e. a `3D` array. This might get you unexpected results if you do `A(:,200)`. You should convert it to a greyscale image using `A = rgb2gray(A)` after reading it with `imread`.

Comment: I tried to convert it using your suggested function but I get the error `A = rgb2gray(A)
??? Undefined function or method 'rgb2gray' for input arguments of type
'uint8'.` Maybe it's perhaps because I am running Matlab2008

Comment: @Thanos: Oh, that's because it is a function in the Image processing toolbox which you might not have installed. You could use: `mean(A,3)` instead, which takes the mean along the third dimension. You only need this if your image is loaded as a 3D-array though, which has `RGB` layers. The mean basically converts `RGB` to grey.

Comment: This converted all the pixels in my image in the number 128 and the output is just a red image...